# unable to write Linq query

Tags: linq

I have an `SQL` query. I want to convert it into a `LINQ` query.
`UserLinks` and `UserRoles` are c# classes that represent dbase tables.

```
select distinct UserLinks.LinkID from UserLinks 
   where RoleID in (select RoleID from UserRoles where UserID=1) and UserLinks.Enable='true'
```

Comment: Can you also show us what you have tried in LINQ?

Answer (score 4):

```
var roleIds = UserRoles.Where(u => u.UserID == 1)
                            .Select(r=>r.RoleID)
                            .ToList();
var result = UserLinks.Where(u => roleIds.Contains(u.RoleID) && u.Enable)
                            .Select(l => l.LinkID)
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: i am getting error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'true' to data type int." for Line  var result = tblUserLinks.Where(u => roleIds.Contains(u.RoleID) && u.Enable)

Comment: Enable is a boolean field(true if link is accesible to user false otherwise)

Comment: error-Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool'

Comment: See i have a table UserLinks(LinkID,LinkName,RoleID,Enable) where I am storing all roleid and corresponding linkid,linkname and setting enable to true if that link is accessible to the user with that roleid

Comment: Also a user can have mutiple roles.Hence i am retrieving List of roles first

Comment: Then which column you have  'true'? there is type mismatch between database and your model check every database column and verify

Comment: ok..thanks...it worked..there was mismatach..and we have to write true without quotes.. u.Enable==true